# How do debuggers get line numbers of commands?

Tags: c++, debugging, line-numbers

I'm trying to get line numbers of address I collected in a stackwalk by using symgetlinefromaddr64, but I can't seem to get addresses of simple commands or their lines.
for example, if i'm looking at the method:

```
void Test(int g)
{
  g++;
  DoSomething(g);
  g--;
}
```

I'll get only the line number of "DoSomething", but I want the line numbers of "g++" etc.
I suppose it is doable because debuggers do it.
how can I do it myself in c++ on windows?

Comment: Is this for Release build code?  Yes, those lines don't generate any code, the function body gets translated to DoSomething(g+1) for example.

Comment: no, just debug builds...

Answer (score 0):

A stack walk will only retrieve addresses that are stored on the stack, which pretty much means function calls. If you want the address of your `g++` or `g--`, you'll need to use something other than a stack walk to get them (e.g., [`SymGetFileLineOffsets64`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681328%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)). If you're starting from a stackwalk and have info from `SymGetLineFromAddr64`, you can use [`SymGetLineNext64`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681332%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`SymGetLinePrev64`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681347%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to get information about the surrounding lines.

Comment: But as far as I understand these functions give me the address from the line number. I want to go the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do it is to use compiler generated symbol files like the `*.pdb` files for microsoft visual studio compilers (pdb stands for program database). These files contain all symbols used during the compilation step. Even for a release compilation you'll get information about the symbols in use (some may have be optimized away).

The main disadvantage is that this is highly compiler dependent/specific. gcc for example may include symbol information in the executable so-file or executable. Other compilers have other formats...

What compiler do you use (name/version)?

Comment: Then you may try to use these pdbs, that is what the debugger also does. No pdb: no source level debugging, mismatching pdb: then the highlighted lines are not matching the current state in the program being debugged. Pdbs definitively contain the info you need. But it is not an open format. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd4f8bd1(v=VS.90).aspx